# Loading Jquery tab from maphilight href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen many threads about this online but none seem to provide a workable solution. I am simply trying to toggle different tabs in a Jquery UI tabs widget with an external href

The closest I feel I have got with this problem was with this solution, pasted below, which does not seem to work:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tabs2').tabs();

    $('.open-tab').click(function(event) {
        var tab = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#tabs2').tabs('select', tab);
  });
 });


  </script>

<div id="tabs2">


          <ul>
                    <li><a href="#tabs2-1">Tab header 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs2-2">Tab header 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs2-3">Tab header 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs2-4">Tab header 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs2-5">Tab header 5</a></li>
          </ul>


  <div id="tabs2-1">
  Tab Content 1
  </div>
  <div id="tabs2-2">
  Tab Content 2
  </div>
  <div id="tabs2-3">
  Tab content 3

  </div>
  </div>
```

The reason I want to load the tabs with external hrefs is because I will be loading the tab from a david lynch maphilight utility. An example of such a link is as follows:

```
 <area class="EU"  shape="poly" title="France" href="#tabs2-1"  coords="353,108,345,107,345,104,347,100,345,96,342,94,339,92,339,91,345,91,345,89,348,90,351,88,353,85,359,88,366,91,366,92,362,97,363,99,362,99,365,103,362,106,358,105,354,106,353,108">
```

As you can see from above the href gives you the ID of the link, so I don't want an indexed solution... Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am slowly but surely starting to lose my sanity and I think I have already broken the enter key :-) Thanks in advance!

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/spyt9/

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: yeah, and use `return false;` in last line of your function when you trying to trigging an anchor ( `<a>` ) onclick event.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle guys: http://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/spyt9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manipulate your fiddle, it's working greate.
[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spyt9/1/)

I've just use `return false` :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tabs2').tabs();

    $('.open-tab').click(function(event) {
        var tab = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#tabs2').tabs('select', tab);
        return false;
  });
 });
```

---

**Edit:
your html code is wrong, you should use the selector in your jQuery for you link, it's working know by this : 
`<a href="#tabs2-1" class="open-tab">TEST 1</a>`
try it : http://jsfiddle.net/spyt9/4/**

Comment: Hello OMiD, thank you for your input. I must be missing something, but your solution does not seem to be working. When I tried your Jsfiddle and clicked on the TEST link nothing happened..?

Comment: try this one : http://jsfiddle.net/spyt9/4/ but remember to go to another tab and then click on test, your selector use classes but you don't have any classes on your external href ! i just add class to your html : `<a href="#tabs2-1" class="open-tab">TEST 1</a>`